# Saving the state of an AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, local-storage, angular-cookies

Is it possible to save the state of an AngularJS app using Angular local storage?
I am creating a fairly simple information based app, with quite a bit of content I was hoping to be able to save the users current "location" so that if they close the app and then re open later the app opens at that saved point.

I have been trying to get my head around cookies and local storage and look for related subjects but haven't been able to find anything that relates to this with AngularJS, only jQuery.

Comment: You should use local storage for this kind of purpose instead of cookie, https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: I've used angular-local-storage (https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) for this.  I have found it to be quite stable and well documented.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have looked into this as well and have looked at saving input text which works great, but it is the actual ability to save the current browsing state that I am struggling with. ie, if they close the page and re-open later it will take them back to the same place. Will keep digging though!

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this issue? I solved it in the following three steps:

1. In a angular config phase where I intercept permissions I have
   additionally a `$transitions.onSuccess` hook. I listen on all
   transitions successes and store the current state name - unless its signin or signout

   ```
   $transitions.onSuccess('*', function(trans) {
     var currentState = trans.router.stateService.current.name;
     if (currentState !== 'signin' &&
     currentState !== 'signout') {
       $localStorage.storeState(trans.router.stateService.current.name);
     }
   });
   ```
2. In the signin/authentication process or whatever place you check if a user is already authenticated you will redirect a user to some state and redirect the user to the previous state

   ```
   var previousState = $localStorage.getState() || Authentication.redirectState;

   if (Authentication.isAuthenticated()) $state.go(previousState);
   ```
3. In the storage factory I delete the stored state on signout